# Server 2012 R2 in place upgrade to server 2016 or 2019 error after first reboot

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, windows-server-2016, upgrade

I'm trying to do in place upgrade from server 2012 R2 to server 2016 or 2019. After installation part and after first restart I get error

> The installation failed in the FIRST_BOOT phase with an error durin BOOT operation

[image]

after I click Close system is returned to Server 2012 R2.

How can I do upgrade ? Migration is not an option (server does not have any roles, just sql instance and some custom software.).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the host server 2012. I had to update the host to server 2016/2019, then upgrade the virtual machine configuration version and then I managed to do in place upgrade.